# Iterating children of a TVertScrollBox

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe2

I have a single `TForm` with a single `TVertScrollBox`. I have added 6 `TPanels` as children of this `TVertScrollBox`.

I would like to iterate over each of these panels and check the `Tag` property of each, but I can't find the correct method to do so.

For testing, I've added an `OnClick` event handler for one of the panels that contains the following code:

```c
void __fastcall TForm1::Panel1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < this->VertScrollBox1->ChildrenCount; ++i)
    {
        ShowMessage("Child: " + this->VertScrollBox1->Children[i]->Name);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < this->VertScrollBox1->ComponentCount; ++i)
    {
        ShowMessage("Component: " + this->VertScrollBox1->Components[i]->Name);
    }
}
```

It seems the `ChildrenCount` property always returns `2`, and the `Name` displayed by `ShowMessage` for each of these children is an empty string, even though each panel has a unique `Name` property.

The `ComponentCount` property always returns `1`, and again- the displayed `Name` is always an empty string.

Can someone tell me which properties or methods to use to iterate over these children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children & ChildrenCount are the correct properties to use but it sounds like your panels are being stored in a container stored within the scrollbox. (I've seen this in other components and I'm not at my dev machine to research).

Check the Classnames of the two children, and what their children are. When you've astablished which child (identified by ClassName) is the container, you'll know how to drill down to your panels.

Comment: Perfect! The `TVertScrollBox` object was reporting two children: objects of type `TLayout` and `TScrollContent`. All of my panels were children of that `TScrollContent` object. Thanks